# How to close the twitter login pop up window manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created my customized twitter login button for my site using  [@Anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome) . My problem is that i want to close the twitter login pop up window manually as my pop up window will not close automatically as it redirects to the url i have provided and does not close.

Below is my code which im working:

```
     twttr.anywhere(function (T) {

           var currentUser,

            screenName,

            profileImage,

            profileImageTag;

    document.getElementById("tweet").onclick = function () {

      T.signIn();

    };
     T.bind("authComplete", function (e, user) {

     window.location.reload();

    });
        if (T.isConnected()) {

          currentUser = T.currentUser;        
          var add = currentUser.data('name'); //Getting user name from its twitter account

          var n = add.split(" ");

          document.getElementById('firstName').value = n[0];
          alert(document.getElementById('firstName').value);
          document.getElementById('LastNm').value = n[1];
          //T("#twitter-connect-placeholder").connectButton();
            twttr.anywhere.signOut();
            } else {

          //T("#twitter-connect-placeholder").connectButton();

           /* Making the text box value empty*/
           document.getElementById('firstName').value = "";
          document.getElementById('LastNm').value = "";

          /* Making the text box value empty*/
        };

  });
```

Comment: Why did you jquery as a tag if your are not using it at all?

Comment: I'm using Jquery in other part of code, and i used Jquery tag so that if any solution is there regarding Jquery also i can use it.